# If Blog id is AND If user can

Tags: php, wordpress

I am running a Wordpress Multisite and using general theme for both site ID 1 and ID 2.

I have placed a div box with a text paragraph into one of the theme's template files :

```
<article class="content-area">

            <div class="my-div-container">
               <p class="text-message">
                  //message
               </p>
            </div>

</article>
```

Basically what I am trying to achieve is the following :

If the BLOG ID is 1 and if the user role is "author" in the same time,then display the div with the following message in the text paragraph : "Hello Tester"

But if the BLOG ID is 2 and the user role is "author" in the same time, then display the div with this message instead : "Hi, this is Tester"

But if none of these apply then don't display any div at all.

I am stuck and just can't get my head around it. I am getting syntax errors, but don't know how to fix it. I am trying the following :

```
<?php
global $blog_id;
if ($blog_id == 1) AND current_user_can('author')) {
   <div class="my-div-container">
                   <p class="text-message">
                      Hello Tester
                   </p>
                </div>
} elseif ($blog_id == 2) AND current_user_can('author')) {
   <div class="my-div-container">
                   <p class="text-message">
                      Hi, this is Tester
                   </p>
                </div>
} else {
//im not sure if this is meant to be left empty to not show anything at all
}
?>
```

I'm quite new to this and really struggling, could somebody please show me how this can be done ? Many Thanks

Comment: You're mixing php and html code... when starting your html-code (divs) you should add ?> before <div class="..." and after the html-code </div> you should add <?php

Comment: Awesome, that has done the trick .. Can I ask for an explanation ? I thought that <?php is a php opening tag and then ?> php closing tag. So how come i place the div inside the these tags being the other way around ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (($expression) && ($expression)) {
}
```

Comment: ha .. i see .. that was simple .. thanks .. is the rest of the syntax ok ?

Comment: Looks like it; In php operators are (OR) -> || , (AND) -> && ... always group your expressions globally and individually for more readability and obviously for logic.

example:

if ((($1 == 0) || ($1 == 1)) && ($this == true)) {
} else {
}

Comment: If that was the answer you were looking for don't forget to mark it as the correct answer.. :)

Comment: thanks, almost there, dreamweaver gives me syntax error in the lines where i am calling the div and the paragraph .. do I need to use echo here or wrap it into php tag ?

Comment: Yes of course... you can do this:

<?php
if ($exp) {
?>
html here
<?php
}
?>

If that doesn't work... use echo.